# How to add ripple to Android TextView for click and LongClick

Tags: android, textview

I have an Android `TextView` that requires both a `Click` and `LongClick` listener.

Im trying to add the ripple effect for both types of click and have managed it "partially" however the user experience is very poor.

I couldnt get the ripple effect to work on the `TextView` at all.

Therefore following other SO suggestions I wrapped the `TextView` in a `FrameLayout` as follows:-

```
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/digit_distance_view_wrapped"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/digit_distance_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lcd_digital"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/initial_gauge_2dp"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/speed_limit_text_size" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

and set `Click` and `LongClick` listeners on the FrameLayout.

While this does work, the user has to click on specific portions of the view, e.g. click on edges round the view.

Clicking in the body of the `TextView` does nothing.

what am I doing wrong?

How can I allow the user to click anywhere within the `TextView`, trigger the click listeners and see a ripple effect?

Heres my Activity listener code:-

```
private lateinit var digitDistanceViewWrapped: View
private lateinit var digitDistanceView: TextView

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        manageFullScreen()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

        digitDistanceViewWrapped = findViewById(R.id.digit_distance_view_wrapped)
        digitDistanceView = findViewById(R.id.digit_distance_view)
        digitDistanceViewWrapped.setOnClickListener(this@DashboardActivity)

        digitDistanceViewWrapped.setOnLongClickListener {
            TripDialogFragment().show(supportFragmentManager, "Trip")
            return@setOnLongClickListener true
        }
```

Comment: Where do you listen for the events?

Comment: You should set `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` instead of `foregroud`.

Comment: @sdex I had tried that, however I had been testing on a Samsung Tablet where neither foreground or backgraound worked. When I tested on Pixel or Huawei phone foreground works as expected.